# Does mysqli_stmt::result_metadata return false on insert, update, delete queries?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm a bit not understanding - on update, insert, delete queries result_metadata returns false? Because:

```
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
if($meta === false){
    throw new Exception(...));
}
```

throws the exception when i try to run update, insert or delete query. But it should be false only on error. (from php manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is intended to return data about the data you've just made a query about (metadata!).  The action of inserting rows, updating rows, and deleting rows usually doesn't actually return a result set.

(At least not in MySQL.  In certain other databases, like Postgres, there's the `RETURNING` clause...)

[From the comments on the `mysqli_stmt_result_metadata` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php):

> If result_metadata() returns false but error/errno/sqlstate tells you no error occurred, this means your query is one that does not produce a result set, i.e. an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query instead of a SELECT query.
>
> This is stated in the documentation where it says "If a statement passed to mysqli_prepare() is one that produces a result set, mysqli_stmt_result_metadata() returns the result object", but it might not be clear to everyone what this entails exactly.

Comment: Oh thank you, but then how to detect whether there was error when calling the result metadata function or it was insert/update/delete query?

Comment: [Check for an error](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) or poke at the [SQLSTATE](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.sqlstate.php) -- if they contain an error, there's your error.  If they don't contain an error, there was no error.